# Not understanding the different parse of the rate() function

Tags: prometheus

I'm really stumped here with trying to figure out the `rate()` function for Prometheus. Looking at [the documentation for `rate()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/functions/#rate()), I'm failing to understand their example:

```
rate(http_requests_total{job="api-server"}[5m])
```

And the description:

> The following example expression returns **the per-second rate** of HTTP requests as measured **over the last 5 minutes**, per time series in the range vector

That 5 minutes is stumping me. You're getting the per-second rate of requests (even though a scrape would be, for instance, every 15s) but where does the "over the last 5 minutes" come into play? I'm looking at a graph that spans 30 minutes, and "over the last 5 minutes" means what with that query/equation?

Thanks in advance. Hoping somebody can explain this in different terms!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every vertical slice of the graph, the rate will be calculated over the 5 minutes before it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! A couple of follow up questions: so the rate here would be, per second, the average over the past 5 minutes? That makes sense. The second question is, I'm not seeing what the effect of saying "past 5 minutes" vs "past 30 seconds" would be. I see the differences in the graph, but could you explain that another way?

Comment: I'm going to be honest, here, I don't think `rate()` is what I'm looking for after all. If I have a time series array of the following values: `[3, 5, 9, 16, 23, 69]`. If those values are captured every 15 seconds, I'd like to find out the *differences* between those time slots. So I'd like the output of `[3, 2, 4, 7, 7, 46]`. Is `rate()` what I'm looking for here? Seeing as how rate is the "average", I'm not looking for that. I'm looking for the change over time. Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps it's `delta()` that I'm looking for.

Comment: The bit in `[]` controls how far back the `rate` looks when averaging. `delta` is not for use with counters, and generally to be avoided.

Comment: If `delta` isn't for counters (this isn't really a counter persay, it's really the amount of CPU time, which I guess the way node_exporter pulls it, is ever-increasing), then what would I use to accomplish this?

Comment: @ThomasStringer found a solution? I guess you would need `increase` and time interval 15s. But I think this will be error prone a lot, because the timestamps won't probably match exactly 15s multiples.